# How long does the Blackberry App World review process take?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

Does anyone have an idea of how long the Blackberry App World review process takes?  We've had an app posted for a week with no additional information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you put an app in app world, it normally takes between 1 and 2 weeks to get an answer but it can vary quite a lot and go up to one month or so (depending on how effecient RIM testing teams)

I would wait another week, and go from there

Comment: It took almost exactly two weeks:  July 26, 2010 - August 6, 2010.

Answer (score 1):

around 2 weeks sounds about right

Answer (score 0):

As it to me, 3 work days generally.